# How to know the allocation of kafka partition

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, apache-kafka, pykafka

I'm using **kafka 0.9.0** with pykafka as a url queue in scrapy, and the topic i used have 30 partitions with 4 consumers.

It works properly at first, but when it worked about a couple of hours the kafka seems having a problem with rebalancing the partitons, and i got some infomations like

> Unable to acquire partition < pykafka.partition.Partition at 0x7f0b422cbfd0 (id=23) >. Retrying

than it raise two exceptions

> **pykafka.exceptions.ConsumerStoppedException**
>
> **pykafka.exceptions.PartitionOwnedError**

So I want to know the allocation of kafka partition. i use the **kafka-consumer-groups.sh** like

**./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper host:port --group name --describe**

which mention on kafka's document, but i got a empty list.

Comment: In 0.9.0.0, you have to make the consumer group active before checking its status.

Comment: i'm new to kafka so first i want to know what is meaning of an inactive group. Is the so call inactive means that there is no consumer in that group consume topic recently? And I found this problem is 'normal' in pykafka's balancedconsumer, when i use kafka-python all things work fine, so i think the pykafka has some problem itself @amethystic

Comment: Did you run kafka-consumer-groups after you stop the consumer application?

Comment: Please add your code to question